# neo4j cypher, performance on specifying labels when id(n) is in conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

has anyone tested/knows if - when querying a Neo4j database with Cypher - specifying the

```
MATCH node:labels
```

makes the selection faster even if

```
WHERE id(node) = x
```

is in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE ID(n) = {x}
RETURN n
```

should be negligibly faster than

```
MATCH (n:MyLabel)
WHERE ID(n) = {x}
RETURN n
```

Both queries first get the node by internal id but while the first query returns the second filters the result on `hasLabel(n:MyLabel)`.

It's a good example of where its possible to overuse labels. Similarly, if for the pattern `(a:Person {name:"Étienne Gilson"})-[:FRIEND]->(b:Person)-[:FRIEND]->(c:Person)` I know that only `:Person` nodes have `-[:FRIEND]-` relationships, there is no point in filtering `b` and `c` on that label. If a remote node should be retrieved from index then the label should be included to indicate that, i.e. `-[:FRIEND]->(b:Person {name:"Jacques Maritain"})`, but when no (indexed) property is included in that part of the pattern, the nodes will be reached by traversal and if only people have friends an additional filter on `hasLabel(b:Person)` would be pointless.

I understand [this blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/12/learning-about-bitmaps/) to mean that filtering on a label is as cheap as a bitwise `&`, so performance difference should be very small.